# get_posts - check if custom field has content?

Tags: get-posts

I have this loop that works fine but I have to check if the custom fields of the post objects ("houses") have content. I try this with "isset" and nothing happens. Tried "isset", too but same problem.

```
$args2 = array (
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'houses'
);
$custom_posts2 = get_posts($args2);
foreach ( $custom_posts2 as $custom_post2 ) {

// check here if custom post type opjects custom field "sz_website" has content
if ( !empty ($custom_post2->post_website)) {
    echo '<div class="wpcf7-list-item-field">' . $custom_post2->sz_website . '</div>';
} else { 
    echo "do nothing"; 
}

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You have custom field (metabox) or you have custom column in the DB table `wp_posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args2 = array (
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'houses'
);
$custom_posts2 = get_posts($args2);
foreach ( $custom_posts2 as $custom_post2 ) {

// check here if custom post type opjects custom field "sz_website" has content
$sz_website = get_post_meta( $custom_post2->ID, 'sz_website', true );

    if ( !empty ($sz_website)) {
        echo '<div class="wpcf7-list-item-field">' . $sz_website . '</div>';
    } else { 
        echo "do nothing"; 
    }

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Let me know if helps.